# C# 9 record: ToHashSet() not producing the desired result

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

```cs
public static class TestRecordTypes
{
    public static void RunTest()
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person("John", "Doe", "home"),
            new Person("John", "Doe", "Away"),
            new Person("Billy", "Doe", "home"),
            new Person("Billy", "Doe", "home"),
            new Person("Batty", "Bo", "home"),
        };

        var peopleHash = people.ToHashSet();

        Debug.WriteLine($"{peopleHash}");
    }        
}

public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName)
{
    string _location;

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string location):
        this(firstName, lastName)
    {
        _location = location;
    }
}
```

With this test I had hoped that `peopleHash` list would only have 3 records, but I get 4 as the equality appears to be including the non init parameter `location`.

Is there a way to get the list of 3 records I want where the comparison is performed on the init properties only and ignores the additional location parameter?

Comment: You can always implement an `IEqualityComparer<Person>` and pass that to `ToHashSet`

Comment: I guess I could, but if I am doing that I may as well use a standard class.  I feel that there should be a decorator I can use to cause the compiler to ignore the location field.

Comment: @John You can write a source generator and a custom attribute for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to change the `IEquatable<Person>` implementation. For that, you can add `Equal` and override `GetHashCode` in the `record`:

```
public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName)
{
    string _location;

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string location) :
        this(firstName, lastName) => _location = location;

    public virtual bool Equals(Person other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return FirstName == other.FirstName && LastName == other.LastName;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(FirstName, LastName);
}
```

then the test passes:

```
[TestMethod]
public void HashTest()
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>()
    {
        new ("John", "Doe", "home"),
        new ("John", "Doe", "Away"),
        new ("Billy", "Doe", "home"),
        new ("Billy", "Doe", "home"),
        new ("Batty", "Bo", "home"),
    };

    var peopleHash = people.ToHashSet();
    Assert.AreEqual(3, peopleHash.Count);
}
```

Comment: At the end of the day, no matter how you skin this cat, you will always have to redefine Equals and GetHashCode somewhere. Doing it in the record itself seems more convenient to me, though.

Comment: Yeah I agree,  But to me the record type would be more useful if it generated these methods based only on the immutable properties described by: public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName)

Comment: @John You can submit a ticket with the proposal at https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang

Answer (score 0):

Using `IEqualityComparer` like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class TestRecordTypes
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person("John", "Doe", "home"),
            new Person("John", "Doe", "Away"),
            new Person("Billy", "Doe", "home"),
            new Person("Billy", "Doe", "home"),
            new Person("Batty", "Bo", "home"),
        };

        var peopleHash = people.ToHashSet(new MyEqualityComparer());

        Console.WriteLine(peopleHash.Count());
    }        
}

public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName)
{
    string _location;

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string location):
        this(firstName, lastName)
    {
        _location = location;
    }
}

class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person p1, Person p2)
    {
        if (p1 == null && p2 == null)
           return true;
        else if (p1 == null || p2 == null)
           return false;
        else if(p1.FirstName == p2.FirstName && p1.LastName == p2.LastName)
                            
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person p)
    {
        string s = p.FirstName + p.LastName;
        return s.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works for sure but in my mind seams to defeat the point of using a record in the first case. As this would work for struct/class too

Comment: As documented by Microsoft: *"We recommend that you derive from the EqualityComparer<T> class instead of implementing the IEqualityComparer<T> interface, because the EqualityComparer<T> class tests for equality using the IEquatable<T>.Equals method instead of the Object.Equals method. "*

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have to admit it didn't make a lot of sense to me either, but you never totally know with Microsoft.